# Single value in an array not calulcated correctly with a function

Tags: arrays, math

I've been working at this for a long time and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the surfGrav value for Uranus, is being output as such a rediculously large number. Basically the program generates surface gravity based on the planets mass and radius. It's only Uranus's value; everything else is fine. I've double checked the values with Google, but to no avail.
Also, this is for a computer science course of mine, so i can't just modify the utput to be what I want, I have to fix what I already have.
The value should be well under that of Jupiter, to put that in perspective.
Thanks for your help!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class GravityV1 
{

public static String[] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

public static int[] radii = {2439000, 6052000, 6378000, 3397000, 71492000, 60268000, 2559000, 24764000};

public static double[] mass = {3.30E+23, 4.87E+24, 5.98E+24, 6.42E+23, 1.90E+27, 5.69E+26, 8.68E+25, 1.02E+26};

public static double constantGrav = 6.67E-11;

public static double a;

//constructors
private static PrintWriter outFile;

//main method
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("gravity1.txt"));
    System.out.println("                       Planetary Data                            ");
    System.out.println("Planet          Diameter(km)        Mass(kg)         g (m/s^2)   ");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
        double surfGrav = surfGrav(i);
        System.out.printf("%8s%15d%20.2e%16.4f%n", planets[i], (2 *radii[i]), mass[i], surfGrav);
        txtGrav(i);
    }
    outFile.close();
}

//this method requires the planet as input. Then it will output and calculate the surface gravity
public static double surfGrav (int planet)
{
    return (constantGrav * mass[planet]) / (Math.pow(radii[planet], 2));
}
//print output to text file too
public static void txtGrav (int arrayInput) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    a = (surfGrav(arrayInput));
    if (arrayInput == 2) {
        a = Math.round(a);
    }
    outFile.printf("%.2f%n", a);
}

}

Output:         
g (m/s^2)   

3.7001
8.8686
9.8052
3.7108
24.7950
10.4488
884.1073 <--- what
11.0939
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you missed one `0` in the Uranus radius: `25590000`. (though this value is a little bit different from what I can find in Internet).

Comment: I can't even begin to justify that silly mistake in my math. Thanks a bunch for pointing that out. I really need to sleep...